# How to get the result of a payable transaction using near-api-js?

Tags: nearprotocol

When calling a contract method with attached deposits, you are redirected to the NEAR wallet for approving the transaction. How can the contract frontend app get the result of the transaction after returning from the wallet?

Comment: We are working on this at the moment and I'll try to come back and update when it's clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced the same problem. For this moment near-api set transaction info in the browser url. So you get the transaction hash from url after returning from the wallet. Then using transaction hash get info about it using `near-api-js`:

```
const { providers } = require("near-api-js");

//network config (replace testnet with mainnet or betanet)
const provider = new providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  "https://archival-rpc.testnet.near.org"
);

const TX_HASH = "9av2U6cova7LZPA9NPij6CTUrpBbgPG6LKVkyhcCqtk3";
// account ID associated with the transaction
const ACCOUNT_ID = "sender.testnet";

getState(TX_HASH, ACCOUNT_ID);

async function getState(txHash, accountId) {
  const result = await provider.txStatus(txHash, accountId);
  console.log("Result: ", result);
}
```

Documentation: https://docs.near.org/docs/api/naj-cookbook#get-transaction-status

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Use provider.txStatus like Tom Links said. But the cons : we only know transaction success or fail but not the response from smart contract.
2. Seperate deposit api and actions api -> User must deposit before call  actions api, so we can read the response.